# magento product visibility

Tags: mysql, magento

Is there a way by mysql to set ALL product visibility to catalog, search?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

open up the `eav_attribute` table and find the row where `attribute_code` = visibility.  Take note of the `attribute_id`, most likely it will be 85. Also take note that `backend_type` = int.  This tells you that the attribute is stored in `catalog_product_entity_int`. So, now you can run:

```
update `catalog_product_entity_int` set value = 4 where attribute_id = 85
```

(assuming of course that the attribute_id was 85!)

Make sure you backup the database before you run it.

HTH,
JD